# Prove (if the statement is correct) $f^{-1} (\bigcap_{i \in J} B_{i} ) = \bigcap_{i \in J} f^{-1}(B_{i}).$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $f : S \rightarrow T$ be a function. If $\{B_{i} | i \in J \}$ is a set of subsets of $T$, Show that $f^{-1} (\bigcap_{i \in J} B_{i} ) = \bigcap_{i \in J} f^{-1}(B_{i}).$

Sometimes I am given wrong statements to try to prove and then get stuck at a point that help me correct the erroneous statement.

1. I feel like this statement is incorrect, but I am unable to create an example to show this, could anyone help me in clarifying what conditions should my example satisfy and what it should not? so that I could create it.
2. Will the proof differ if the indexing set $J$ is countable or uncountable, if so how? (this question is not answered in the suggested question)

Comment: It is true for any indexing set $J$.

Comment: How do you know?@KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: Verify that each side is contained in the other.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy how this verification differs between countable and uncountable sets?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy what about my first question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the strategies I can use to prove $f^{-1}(S \cap T) = f^{-1}(S) \cap f^{-1}(T)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228711/what-are-the-strategies-i-can-use-to-prove-f-1s-cap-t-f-1s-cap-f)

Comment: @EmiliaDunfelt No, the second question is not answered in the suggested question Also the first question is not answered clearly.

Comment: 1) "I feel like this statement is incorrect." You are wrong there (see the answer given by William). Extra conditions are not necessary and the counterexample that you are after does not exist, hence cannot be created. 2) There is no essential difference between countable and uncountable index set. Does this answer all your questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $x$ we have $$x\in f^{-1}(\cap_{i\in I}B_i)\iff$$ $$f(x)\in \cap_{i\in I}B_i\iff$$ $$ \forall i\in I\,(f(x)\in B_i)\iff$$ $$ \forall i\in I\,(x\in f^{-1}B_i) \iff$$ $$ x\in \cap_{i\in I}f^{-1}B_i.$$

Comment: Why did not we use induction in the proof?

Comment: @Secretly . Because $I$ can be any set, finite or infinite.

Comment: do you mean countable or uncountable? I think induction can be done for finita as well as infinite sets

Comment: ANY set.........

Answer (score 1):

Let $C$ be a collection of sets.
Theorem: 
$f^{-1}$($ \cap$ $C$) = $ \cap$ { $f^{-1}(A) : A \in$ $C$ }.
Proof:
x in $f^{-1}$($\cap$ $C$) iff
$f(x) \in \cap$ $C$ iff
for all $A \in C$, $f(x) \in A$ iff
for all $A \in C$, $x \in f^{-1}(A)$ iff
$x \in \cap$ { f$^{-1}(A) : A \in C $}.

Comment: I think this does not answer all my questions

Comment: Things might clear up a bit more for the OP if an index set is used.

Comment: @Secretly.  It does so where I used C for the index set.